# Qual melhor tecnologia server side para servir informações a um software multiplataforma?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, http

Sabemos que é possível acessar o *Facebook* de vários clientes, como browsers, android, iOS etc. Sei que via browser é usado o protocolo HTTP (obviamente) com tecnologias como *AJAX* e *Comet*(chat, notificações em tempo real).

**Dúvida:**

Qual seria a melhor tecnologia na parte do servidor para que plataformas moveis (android, iOS) e browsers possam interagir entre si?

TCP sockets? Requisições HTTP/Restful? SOAP?

Dei o Facebook como exemplo, para entenderem qual minha necessidade(acesso multiplataforma).

**Objetivo:**

Desenvolver um software multiplataforma que possuam as mesmas funcionalidades independente da plataforma.

Comment: Não ficou claro a sua dúvida. Por favor, edite e tente ser um pouco mais claro.

Comment: Editei. Havia ficado confuso pois não sei a palavra-chave que define a minha necessidade, resumindo seria um software multiplataforma que precisa interagir entre si independente da plataforma.

Comment: @GustavoPiucco sua pergunta continua sendo baseada em opniões e muito ampla. Nós lidamos melhor com perguntas que possuam respostas bem definidas. Esse tipo de pergunta se encaixa melhor em algum fórum ou grupo de discussão.

Comment: _"Sei que via browser é usado o protocolo HTTP (obviamente)"_ - E os WebSockets sendo padronizados pelo W3C, ficam de lado? Acho que a tendência é Realtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No que se refere aos clientes mobile, a única solução viável são as interfaces [RESTFUL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST), que utilizam o HTTP e seus diferentes verbos: POST, GET, DELETE e PUT.

E tendo uma inteface restful robusta e bem estruturada, você consegue servir qualquer tipo de cliente. Não posso dizer com certeza como o Facebook funciona, mas duvido muito que seja algo diferente disso.

Answer (score 1):

O Facebook utiliza várias tecnologias para prover seus vários serviços. É muito difícil ficarmos aqui citarmos aqui como funciona cada um deles.

Mas com certeza, a mundo está caminhando para utilização de RESTful para integrar aplicações.

Comment: _"o mundo está caminhando para utilização de RESTful para integrar aplicações."_ - Por que não Realtime? Acho que a tendência é essa, vide a padronização de WebSockets pelo W3C.

Comment: @Piovezan Também, essa é uma questão complicada cara, que renderia discussões eternas. Mas se baseando pelos grandes webservices atualmente, eu diria que a a grande maioria hoje é baseada em RESTful.

Comment: O problema do RESTful é a falta de escalabilidade. Compare neste exemplo [7.2 milhões de requisições RESTful vs 50k de Realtime](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/2013/10/31/fundamentals-realtime-web-realtime-web-functionality.html).